# How can a function within a with block use a table defined in this same with block

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH
    FUNCTION f (a in integer)
        RETURN INTEGER
    IS
        ret integer;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT (*) into ret
        FROM B;
        RETURN ret +a;
    END;
B(b1) as (select 1 from dual),
select f(3) from dual;
```

Oracle say :

> [Error] Execution (6: 1): ORA-06552: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

dbfiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ff90cec6ed25724bad9c215f0173607a)say :

> ORA-00903: invalid table name

I think that Oracle doesn't know the table B because, she is defined after f is defined. But I can't change the order of what is defined in a with block. The functions must be defined before the table.

Does somebody has a solution to use in a function a table which is defined in the same with block?

I can't declare the B table inside the function, because I intend to create others function that use the table B. I don't want to defined B more than 2 times.

Comment: There's nothing smart I can say about it; only that what you observed is correct (as far as I can tell). You can't declare a table before a function; if you declare it afterwards, function doesn't see it. If it was e.g. `... from dual` (instead of `from B`), your code would work. Therefore, yes - I'd say you're correct. I don't have a solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `B` inside the function:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION f (a in integer)
  RETURN INTEGER
IS
  ret integer;
BEGIN
  WITH B(b1) AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT COUNT (*) into ret
  FROM B;
  RETURN ret +a;
END;
SELECT f(3)
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or, do the counting outside the function:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION f (
  a   IN PLS_INTEGER,
  cnt IN PLS_INTEGER
)
  RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN cnt +a;
END;
B (b1) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT f(3, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b)) AS value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which both output:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 4 |

---

#### However

If you want to `COUNT` inside the function and reference a subquery factoring clause that is defined later then you are out of luck as you need to have the table defined before the function.

The syntax diagram states:

> #### select::=
>
> [image: SELECT syntax]
>
> #### subquery::=
>
> [image: SUBQUERY syntax]
>
> #### query_block::=
>
> [image: QUERY_BLOCK syntax]
>
> #### with_clause::=
>
> [image: WITH_CLAUSE]
>
> #### subquery_factoring_clause::=
>
> [image: SUBQUERY_FACTORING_CLAUSE syntax]

Although there is a clear chain in the syntax diagram `SELECT`, `SUBQUERY`, `QUERY_BLOCK`, `WITH_CLAUSE`, `SUBQUERY_FACTORING_CLAUSE` and back to `SUBQUERY` if, in practice you try to do something like nesting `WITH` clauses:

```sql
WITH B (b1) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
),
C (value) AS (
  WITH FUNCTION f (a in integer)
    RETURN INTEGER
  IS
    ret integer;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (*) into ret
    FROM B;

    RETURN ret +a;
  END f;
  SELECT f(3)
  FROM   DUAL 
)
SELECT value
FROM   c;
```

You will get the error:

```
ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=eab5d0f23c1d733fa64e868e300c35cb)*